# Checking if date in database is greater than current time

Tags: php, pdo

I have a PHP script to check if the date stored in the database is greater, equal or less than the current time.

- If it is greater or equal, it echos 'greater'.
- If it isn't greater, it echoes 'not'

My issue is that even if the time in the database **is not** greater or equal to the current time, it echos 'greater' (when it's supposed to echo 'not').

Date stored in the database:

[image]

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$time_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();
if($row['BannedUntil'] <= $time_stamp) {
echo 'Greater';
}else{
echo 'not';
}
```

Comment: don't compare strings: `if(strtotime($row['BannedUntil']) <= time()) {`

Comment: @splash58 Thank you. Using that, I was able to solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use MySQL Date and Time Functions `DATEDIFF`**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$time_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT DATEDIFF(`BannedUntil`,NOW()) AS `daysUntil` FROM table");
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();
if($row['daysUntil'] >= 0) {
echo 'Greater'; // banned
}else{
echo 'not'; // not banned
}
```

Comment: Would this be necessary, as `if(strtotime($row['BannedUntil']) <= time()) {` seems to work fine?

Comment: Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/58348. Result is an integer representing number of days. It can be positive, negative or equal to zero. It is more accurate approach to my opinion. Have you tested it to see if it answers your question?